# Positing user current location

Tags: android

first i would love to thank you for help me,i am develop the android application that contain 3 activities one of them is map.i am using google maps

what i want : 1- when the user open the activity (map) it shows the user her location not the coordinate 2- the user also can be able to positing(pining) any place by using pin and my app must store the coordinates for this pin in variable so i can use it later. PlEASE HELP ME

Answer (score 0):

You should first obtain the user latitude and longitude. Then use the GeoCoder to obtain the address.

You have the complete code here , https://stackoverflow.com/a/3145655/563306

Comment: i try it but when i install the application in my mobile it is give me message "the application is topped unexpectedly"